# Maven: How to disable unwanted Spring annotation configurations from another artifact?

Tags: spring, maven, configuration, dependencies

Let's say I have two local projects A and B which both have annotated configurations, and I want to include some classes from project B (mainly domain classes) to project A. My problem is that, if I have the project B dependency in A, when I actually run A, the B project's configurations are run, and things such as a web server are started.

So my question is: how can I either disable the annotated configurations in B or exclude the classes that have the configurations to stop the unwanted configurations from running?

Comment: I think this will be useful for you go through it http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution (as per Sujata's link) turned out to be quite simple.

Say you have a dependency in project A:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This turns into:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Now in project B, when you add the dependency to project A, A's dependencies that are declared optional will not be loaded.